# Latex: plot 2d csv

Tags: matlab, csv, plot, latex

Presume I have a 2D data set `a` in MATlab `(0)`:

```
a = randi(5);  % (0)
figure; imagesc(a);  % (1)
csvwrite('data.csv',a); % (2)
```

I export the data set as a csv in `(2)`.

In LaTex it is possible to plot a 1D data set with `pgfplots`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0]
        \addplot table {data1d.csv}; (3)
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It would be possible to just export the plot from `(1)` and import it with 
`includegraphics` in LaTex, but it just doesn't look as good as a native plot.

How can I display a 2D data set imported from a csv in LaTex?
Is there a way using pgfplots / tikz as shown in `3` ?

Edit:

The data in the CSV file contains the grayscale values (0-255) of a 2D function plot such as for example: ​​

[image: 2D Image]

--> the data entries of the *.csv file 
would looks something like this:

```
data = [164,167,165,164,162,162,160,159,157,153,152;
     160,151,145,143,150,148,147,147,142,140,140;
                         ...
     161,161,159,153,153,151,150,146,147,148,182]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf] table[x=x,y=y,z=data] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The data.csv file has this content:

```
x y data
0 0 165
1 0 167
2 0 162

0 1 153
1 1 154
2 1 151

0 2 154
1 2 148
2 2 153
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Generally good, BUT: it does something else for me. I'll fiddle around a bit and write more once I figure stuff out.